# How To Append The different Array value in single variable

Tags: php

```
<tr>
    <td><p style="color:#999; font-size:14px; text-align:right;">Please select your Board :</p></td>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="board[]" id="all" value="cbse">CBSE
    <input type="checkbox" name="board[]" id="sci" value="cse/Ise">ICSE/ISE
    <input type="checkbox" name="board[]" id="mat" value="State">State
    <input type="checkbox" name="board[]" id="mat" value="International">International
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><p style="color:#999; font-size:14px; text-align:right;">Please select Subject :</p></td>       
    <td>      
    <input type="checkbox" name="classfivesubject[]" id="all" value="allsubject">All Subject
    <input type="checkbox" name="classfivesubject[]" id="sci" value="science">Science
    <input type="checkbox" name="classfivesubject[]" id="mat" value="maths">Maths
    </td>
    </tr><!--end of select subject row-->
```

Here are my PHP values:

```
$segment=$_SESSION["segment"];
$board=$_POST['board'];
$subject5=$_POST['classfivesubject'];
$segment=implode(",",$segment);
$board=implode(",",$board);
$class5data=implode(",",$subject5);
```

**Again for class8:**

```
$eightboard=$_POST['eightboard'];
$subject8=$_POST['classeightsubject'];
$board=implode(",",$eightboard);
$class8data=implode(",",$subject8);
```

I want store the values like this in my database in a column: classconducted.

```
segment:class I_V
Board:CBSE,STATE
Subject:AllSubject,Maths,Science

segment:class V-VIII
Board:CBSE, STATE
SUbject:AllSubject,Maths,Science
```

My question is how to append all the values in single variable. Assume variable name is classconducted. So that based on the tutor selection class conducted I bring all the data into a single variable and put it into a single column. I hope you understand my question because each tutor is conducting different standard and different subject and different medium. How do I bring all the values in single variable?

I want output like this: classconducted.

```
    segment:class I_V
    Board:CBSE,STATE
    Subject:AllSubject,Maths,Science

    segment:class V-VIII
    Board:CBSE, STATE
    SUbject:AllSubject,Maths,Science
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store json encoded data into a single column like

```
$classconducted = json_encode(array('segment'=>'your segment value','Board'=>'board value','Subject'=>'subject value'));
```

Comment: Thanks .I have done like this. It is showing like this {"segment":["Class I-V Tuition","Class VI-VIII Tuition"],"Board":["cbse","cse\/Ise","State"],"class5Subject":["allsubject","science","maths"],"classeightBoard":["International"],"classeightsubject":["allsubject","maths"]} To display to user what I have do? please see the question once again I have given my output format. guide me?

Comment: check the question . I have given my sample output

Comment: To display you have to decode your column value like, $values = json_decode($your_data,true); and after you can see by print_r and access respected index.

Comment: Also you can make better json that you made. As you can make array having 3 indexes named as 'segment','Board' and 'Subject'.And there are same number of values. Single segment having multiple subjects and boards stored by imploding by ,

Comment: You are correct. can you update your answer in your way. because I am new to this task.that why I have given output answer what I am looking for.Assume It stored in db column like class conducted. Now all the values are stored under class conducted. I will use mysql query to fetch data .after that I will use json_decode. To display result like see my question . I have give sample ouptut .can you please help me. with final  answer.

Comment: Another doubt class5, class8 and engg  has values Here  I have mad the $classconducted = json_encode(array('segment'=>'your segment value','Board'=>'board value','Subject'=>'subject value','tutiton'=>'tuition','class5'=>values,'class8'= values)); board and subject doesnot have values here the columns are mismatching in json_encode is it creates any problem when we display to userside.

Comment: Did you get my question? what happen if the array index does not have values for ex:$classconducted = json_encode(array('segment'=>'your segment value','Board'=>'','Subject'=>''));